# Ruby gem use configuration inside executable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am building a gem that needs a configuration when adding it to a project and also has an executable command.

The structure that I have right now is:

```rb
module MyGem
  class << self
    attr_accessor :configuration
  end

  def self.configure
    self.configuration ||= Configuration.new
    yield(configuration)
  end

  class Configuration
    attr_accessor :base_url

    def initialize
      @base_url = ''
    end
  end

  def self.method_to_run
    puts self.configuration
  end
end
```

Inside the `/bin/my-gem` file in the gem source, I have:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'my-gem'

puts("config: #{MyGem.configuration}")
puts MyGem.method_to_run
```

In this case the output when running `my-gem` is:

```
(empty line)
config:
```

When I enter another project, with the initializer set, inside the `rails console`, the config is set and I can run everything smooth.

How can I use the set configuration from a project even inside the command?

Comment: Where and how do you actually set the configuration? Because currently you only require load an empty config.

Comment: Inside the project where I loaded this gem, I have this:
```
MyGem.configure do |config|
  config.base_url = 'localhost:3000'
end
```

Comment: The gem doesn't know if it is part of a bigger project or is run from an executable command. Therefore you need to load the config file in your executable too.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Any ideas of how I could do that to be compatible with any project that would import this gem?

Comment: I would argue that this would not be easily possible. Imagine you have two projects on your machine and both have this gem installed. When you now call the executable which projects config should it use? I suggest copying the executable into the projects bin folder or to create a rake task in each project.